# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation, (mscorlib)

Tags: sql-server

i'm getting error while trying to do edit the table. Please help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WydhE.png)

Comment: could you little explain what you are trying to do and when this error coming and please mention SQL SERVER version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgraded my sql server to 2014 . The problem was miss match in sql server versions.